# Java Vector Stack Contains Implementation

Tags: java, vector, stack

My contains and remove method is not returning the right output. This program takes a stack of names and use the contains, remove, and empty method. I wrote my methods and I'm using a driver to see if I wrote my methods correctly. I'm pretty sure that all my methods are correct besides contains and remove method. Here's my code

```
    public boolean remove(T obj) {
        if (obj == null)
            return false;
        while (!store.empty() && store.peek().compareTo(obj) < 0) {
            temp.push(store.pop());
        }

        store.pop();

        while(!temp.empty()) {
            store.push(temp.pop());
        }
        size--;
        return true;
    }
```

```
public boolean contains(T obj) {
    while (!store.empty() && store.peek().compareTo(obj) < 0) {
        if (store.peek().equals(obj)) {
            return true;
        } else temp.push(store.pop());
    }
    while(!temp.empty()) {
        store.push(temp.pop());
    }
    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here are implementations of the methods remove and contains:

```
public boolean remove(T obj) {
    if (obj == null)
        return false;
    boolean removed = false;
    while (!store.empty()) {
        if(store.peek().equals(obj)) {
            store.pop();
            size--;
            removed = true;
        }else {
            temp.push(store.pop());
        }
    }

    while (!temp.empty()) {
        store.push(temp.pop());
    }
    return removed;
}

public boolean contains(T obj) {
    while (!store.empty()) {
        if (store.peek().equals(obj)) {
            return true;
        } else
            temp.push(store.pop());
    }
    while (!temp.empty()) {
        store.push(temp.pop());
    }
    return false;
}
```

The problem with your implementation of **remove** was that there was no if statement that tested equality of the objects, which should be removed. The **remove** method also was returning **true** and decrementing size regardless if the object was removed or not.

The problem with **contains** method was that it was never testing equality of objects.

---

You should apply DRY(Don't Repeat Yourself) principle. Having that on mind you should extract code

```
    while (!temp.empty()) {
        store.push(temp.pop());
    }
```

into separate method and don't repeat the same code again and again. Something like this:

```
private void pushFromTempToStore(){
    while (!temp.empty()) {
        store.push(temp.pop());
    }
}
```

Than your methods could look like this:

```
public boolean add(T obj) {
    if (obj == null)
        return false;
    while (!store.empty() && store.peek().compareTo(obj) < 0) {
        temp.push(store.pop());
    }
    store.push(obj);
    pushFromTempToStore();
    size++;
    return true;
}

public boolean remove(T obj) {
    if (obj == null)
        return false;
    boolean removed = false;
    while (!store.empty()) {
        if(store.peek().equals(obj)) {
            store.pop();
            size--;
            removed = true;
        }else {
            temp.push(store.pop());
        }
    }

    pushFromTempToStore();
    return removed;
}


public boolean contains(T obj) {
    while (!store.empty()) {
        if (store.peek().equals(obj)) {
            return true;
        } else
            temp.push(store.pop());
    }
    pushFromTempToStore();
    return false;
}
```

---

Another important thing to have in mind is **testing**. You should use some testing framework, like JUnit or TestNG, instead of a driver. There are plenty of materials to learn about testing. Here is a nice book that helped me a lot [Test-Driven Java Development](https://www.packtpub.com/product/test-driven-java-development/9781783987429). It's a bit dated, so maybe you should try to find some newer resources...